# system.xml fields are not saving in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml

Hi today i'm working on `system.xml` file. it's not saving correctly.

**system.xml**

```
<custom_field translate="label">
     <label>Add Class and it's Params</label>
     <frontend_model>hello/adminhtml_form_field_addclass</frontend_model>
     <backend_model>hello/system_config_backend_addclass</backend_model>
     <sort_order>6</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</custom_field>
```

**Test\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\AddClass.php**

```
<?php

class Test_Hello_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Field_AddClass extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('add_param', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('hello')->__('Add Parameter'),
        ));
        $this->addColumn('add_param_class', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('hello')->__('Add Parameter Class'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('add_param_class_field', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('hello')->__('Add Parameter Class Fields'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('hello')->__('Add Class');
    }

}
```

**Test\Model\System\Config\Backend\AddClass.php**

```
<?php


/**
 * Backend for serialized array data
 *
 */
class Test_Hello_Model_System_Config_Backend_AddClass extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    /**
     * Process data after load
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        Mage::log($value,null,'AddClass');
        //$this->setValue($value);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     */
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        //$this->setValue($value);
        Mage::log($value,null,'AddClass');

    }
}
```

it's saving `core_config_data` table like below formate.

```
path = customtab/custom_attributes/custom_field

value = Array,Array,Array,
```

Logs are created like below formate

```
2015-08-10T10:42:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array,
2015-08-10T10:58:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [_1439204268814_814] => Array
        (
            [add_param] => acceptNewClass
            [add_param_class] => AcceptNewClassFields
            [add_param_class_field] => ID,PrimariContact
        )

    [_1439204284271_271] => Array
        (
            [add_param] => TokenID
            [add_param_class] => 
            [add_param_class_field] => 
        )

    [_1439204298185_185] => Array
        (
            [add_param] => memberID
            [add_param_class] => 
            [add_param_class_field] => 
        )

    [__empty] => 
)
```

how to save & retrieve this?

Any help on this

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to save? Is it just a text field?

Comment: @rob3000, No it's not a text field, i'm not specifying it's type. I'm trying to save just like **AddException** Field from `System->Configuration->Design`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your backend model look like this:

```
class Test_Hello_Model_System_Config_Backend_AddClass extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    /**
     * Process data after load
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $this->setValue(unserialize($value));
        Mage::log($value,null,'AddClass');
        //$this->setValue($value);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     */
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $this->setValue(serialize($value));
        Mage::log($value,null,'AddClass');

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's saving  `a:4:{s:17:"_1439207304052_52";a:3:{s:9:"add_param";s:25:"acceptNewClass";s:15:"add_param_class";s:17:"AcceptNewClassFields";s:21:"add_param_class_field";s:6:"MID,PC";}s:17:"_1439207315045_45";a:3:{s:9:"add_param";s:19:"TokenID";s:15:"add_param_class";s:0:"";s:21:"add_param_class_field";s:0:"";}s:18:"_1439207317859_859";a:3:{s:9:"add_param";s:9:"memberIDP";s:15:"add_param_class";s:0:"";s:21:"add_param_class_field";s:0:"";}s:7:"__empty";s:0:"";}` it's not user friendly to retrieve values. How Can I retrieve Array Values?

Comment: just unserialize the values before using them.

Comment: @M_N You have to unserialize the value. `unserialize($yourValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `backend_model` as

```
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
```

So now the field value will be saved as `serialized` format.

And while get the value you need to `unserialize` the value

```
$myvals = unserialize(Mage::getStoreConfig('myvals'));
```

Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7449/magento-store-config-get-array).